# Performant stable random sort in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, random, discrete-mathematics

I want to query a rather large table (millions of rows), providing a seed value, in a manner that will guarantee a random order - but one that remains stable across multiple queries as long as the same seed is used.

The best I've come up with so far is

```
SELECT TOP n *
      FROM tbl t
  ORDER BY t.int_column % seed, t.int_column
```

Is this a usable approach, both from a performance standpoint and a somewhat-uniform distribution of result rows over different seeds?

Edit:

For context, the stable sort is needed because of multiple - possibly nested - `WHERE NOT IN` queries that operate on the same data set; e.g.

```
SELECT *
  FROM tbl t
 WHERE t.some_criteria = 'some_value'
   AND t.id NOT IN
(
    SELECT TOP n t.id
          FROM tbl t
         WHERE t.some_other_criteria = 'some_other_value'
      ORDER BY t.int_column % seed, t.int_column
)
   AND t.id NOT IN
(
    # etc.
)
```

When the order of the subselects is random, but not stable (i.e. `NEWID()`, `TABLESAMPLE()`), the result rows fluctuate wildly between executions.

Comment: Where is the data being consumed? If you're not passing data off to another stored-procedure or other in-database code then the act of ordering rows according to non-trivial criteria is a view-level concern and should not be in your database code but instead inside your application code.

Comment: @Dai - great question. Please see my edit.

Comment: You'll always sort all records machting the criteria, which can be quite a lot. Are you sure you need all those `NOT IN` clauses? Maybe you can somewhat simplify the query. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, unfortunately. The use case is a selection builder operating on user-supplied criteria; each of the subselects represents one "left sibling" target group whose results need to be excluded from the pool for the next target group (since every entity can only be part of one target group, ever).

Comment: So you select again and again with the query getting bigger and bigger? This may be a case for a temporary table that already includes the sortkey and an index on it. Plus maybe a number for the target group that you set iteratively. (Something along the lines of `update top (50) #temptable set targetgroup = 1 where targetgroup is null and somecriteria = 123 order by sortkey`, `update top (50) #temptable set targetgroup = 2 where targetgroup is null and othercriteria = 456 order by sortkey` etc.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I've already gone the temp table and iterative evaluation route - target group results get written to temp tables, subsequent child target groups use `WHERE id IN #parentTempTable`, sibling groups `WHERE id NOT IN #leftSiblingTempTable`. Effectively, the sort is performed once per TG. Still needs to be stable ;)

Comment: Well, if you fill the temp table once with some sortkey, you don't have to generate one in your queries. It is stable, because it's fix.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - I'm unfortunately stuck with one temp table per target group for the time being because LINQ/Entity Framework. Love your suggestion though; maybe I'll manage to go down that route on the next major rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

If you want random-looking ordering, you can do this with [`HASHBYTES`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql) and some piece of data from the row you're selecting.

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM tbl t
  ORDER BY HASHBYTES('SHA1', CONCAT(STR(t.int_column), 'seed string'))
```

Now, the *performance* of this is a big question. Modern CPUs do SHA1 very quickly, so this might be good enough for your needs.

If you can more about performance and less about "good randomness," you could drop in a simple [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) as the transformation function:

```
SET ARITHABORT    OFF;
SET ARITHIGNORE   ON;
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;

SELECT TOP 100 *
  FROM tbl t
  ORDER BY ((t.int_column + seed_number) * 1103515245 + 12345)
```

This will be faster, but less random.

Comment: The `HASHBYTES()` route is unfortunately about 90% worse performance-wise compared to `modulo`. I couldn't quite test the linear congruential generator perf because it causes an int overflow.

Comment: Never mind the int overflow (`CAST AS bigint` helped), but *less random* is a bit of an understatement; indeed, the order is _very_ stable ;)

Comment: The "randomness" of LC comes from the cases where the integer wraps around a modulo (normally this happens at the max of whatever integer type you're using). I don't actually know how to make SQL Server do wrapped math.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh! I knew I was missing something, that just looked *too* wrong. Shame on me, but then again, it's past 3 AM. Thanks for your input, I'll research wrapped math in sql server some more and will update you if anything comes of it. Cheers!

Comment: The easy option is to slap a `% partition_count` on the back of the `ORDER BY`, but it will be faster if you can just tell SQL Server that you don't care about overflows.

Comment: `SET ARITHABORT OFF; SET ARITHIGNORE ON; SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;` did the trick. Performance-wise, it's exactly the same as `modulo`. Thanks again for the interesting piece of maths :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought... You could add a "RamdomSort" column to you table. That way the the sort order will be truly random but will remain repeatable repeatable until you update the table with new values. Something along these lines...

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD RandomSort INT NOT NULL 
CONSTRAINT df_MyTable_RandomSort DEFAULT(0);


UPDATE mt SET
    mt.RandomSort = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 100000 + 1
FROM
    dbo.MyTable mt;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    dbo.MyTable mt
ORDER BY 
    mt.SomeValue;
```

If the situation warrants it, you could even add a covering, nonclustered index to eliminate the sort operation.